# Closing over local state in Om.Next lifecycle functions

Tags: clojurescript, om-next

I would like to do something similar to Reagent form-3 components, which enable me to define some shared (static) vars to use in lifecycle functions.

Basically my question is how do I construct something equivalent to the `let` in the Reagent code snippet below? I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly using Om's `defui` macro.

A simple example would be to generate an internal id I can access in all lifecycle functions of a specific instance of my component via `gdom/getElement`.

```
(defn my-component
  [x y z]  
  (let [id (gensym "my-component-")]  ;; <-- how to do this in Om?
     (reagent/create-class                 
       {:component-did-mount (...)
        :component-will-mount (...)          
        :reagent-render
         (fn [x y z] (js/console.log id)))) ;; <-- id is available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of digging I found the solution to be a combination of using react's `initLocalState` lifecycle method and `om.next/get-state` as hinted to in Chris' answer.

The general outline becomes as follows:

```
(defui MyComponent
    Object
    (initLocalState [this] {:id (gensym "") ...}) ; <-- the key
    (render [this]
     (let [id (om/get-state this :id)] ...))
    (componentDidmount [this]
     (let [id (om/get-state this :id)] ...))
    ...
```

This approach is more verbose than in Reagent, but I'm fine with that, as it provides equivalent functionality. I use this all the time, so am a little surprised I couldn't find any discussion about this elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `om.next/set-state!`, `om.next/update-state!` and `om.next/get-state` to write to, alter and read from component local state.

However component local state is the poor cousin to app state. To use app state give your `defui` component an *ident* and simply make up a keyword that is part of the component's query. Then setup read and mutate multimethods that dispatch on the keyword you have invented.

As a side note - if you are using Fulcro rather than Om Next you won't need the read multimethod.

Comment: I probably used the wrong terminology, but I'm not looking for a way to modify the component's state. I want to parametrize components once upon instantiation. Om's state-related functions will trigger rerenders etc., which is not what I want. In the Reagent example in OP, every instantiation of `my-component` will have a different `id`, but that `id` will be available in all lifecycle functions of each instantiation. Putting these things in app state seems like major overkill for what I'm trying to do, but maybe I am not entirely in the right mindset yet ...

Comment: Are you saying that some lifecycle functions won't have access to component local state? Another option I didn't mention is a convenient global part of state known as a 'link', that is not related to any particular component, but can be easily accessed from all. Anything that is queried will trigger a render (including these links), however that is academic really.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, you've helped me find the solution!